# It's more than just propinquity

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

Is there a term for the mutual romantic affection for another person that develops as a result of continued or repeated proximity or encounters. I was hoping that "propinquity" would cover that effect, but that only relates to the situational nearness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called the **Propinquity Effect**

> [The propinquity effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propinquity#Propinquity_effect) is the tendency for people to form friendships or romantic relationships with those whom they encounter often, forming a bond between subject and friend. Workplace interactions are frequent and this frequent interaction is often a key indicator as to why close relationships can readily form in this type of environment.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propinquity#Propinquity_effect) In other words, relationships tend to form between those who have a high propinquity. It was first theorized by psychologists Leon Festinger, Stanley Schachter, and Kurt Back in what came to be called the Westgate studies conducted at MIT (1950).
>   
>   Incidentally, *[propinquity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propinquity)* in social psychology refers to **physical or psychological** proximity. … It can mean physical proximity, a kinship between people, or a similarity in nature between things ("like-attracts-like"). Two people living on the same floor of a building, for example, have a higher propinquity than those living on different floors, just as two people with similar political beliefs possess a higher propinquity than those whose beliefs strongly differ.

So, propinquity it is, after all.

Also, in interpersonal attraction, the more often someone interacts with a person, the more pleasing and likeable they find that person. That's the **familiarity principle** ([mere exposure effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mere-exposure_effect)).